# What are these gaps in foundation footing?

Tags: foundation, drainage, cement

A section of foundation I excavated has gaps in the foundation footing. They are uniformly spaced apart and look very intentional. As far as I can tell they are at least 4-5 inches deep (that was as far as I could dig) and are lower than the foundation floor. I don't see any indication of them inside the garage. The foundation wall is poured cement.

The house was built in the 1950s and we think the garage was built around the same time.

I want to make a slope away from the foundation for drainage and, although I found these gaps buried, I am hesitant to bury them again until I know what they are and if they are used for drainage.

[image: exposed foundation footing with evenly spaced gaps going under foundation wall]

Comment: They almost look like 2x4 foot prints(ends).  If they do not go into the wall, I would not worry.  Probably where the forms were place for the wall.

Comment: Yep, from a monolithic pour.  Here's a pic showing similar: https://blog.buildllc.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/BUILD-LLC-Formwork-04.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are inconsequential.  They are marks from the form supports.

Do your grading, but I would recommend placing soil higher than the concrete marks you have unearthed. They are most likely the very bottom of the foundation. You don't want water undermining it.

Comment: yeah these are the wall form supports that sit on the footing form when doing a monolithic pour.  The wood actually typically goes from outside to inside.